# What DB does rails 3 console --sandbox use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, ruby-on-rails-3.2

when I run "rails console --sandbox" I am not able to see inserts in my database.  When I leave the option off I am able to see the data in my development database just fine.  Everything from the console seems to work the same.   I am using postgreSQL as set up in Hartl's rails tutorial.   I have looked in each of the databases, Development, Test, Postgres. But cannot find the data I created using the console. As I am using bundel, I tried with and with out "bundle exec"

Here is my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: sample_app_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: user
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: sample_app_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: user
  password:
```

I suppose this is not critical but I am just very curious what is happening under the covers here.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Not a duplicate but => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340680/rails-script-console-vs-script-console-sandbox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the console acts as one big transaction in sandbox mode, you can see inserts you make only through the console.

If you are connecting to your db through any other method than the console, then it will be using a different connection and the things the console is doing will be hidden from that connection because they are not yet committed.

When a connection talks to a database using a transaction, other database connections can't see any changes it makes until it commits.  The connection with the transaction (in this case, the sandboxed console) is the only connection that can see the changes it makes to the database before rollback.

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Does it run callbacks (eg send email) under this sandbox mode?

Answer (score 5):

You'll never see anything saved in your database using the `--sandbox` option. Any changes made with this mode will be reverted when you exit the console.

When you start your console with this option you can read: **Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit**

**More info**

If you try again you'll see `SAVEPOINT active_record_1` before the insert and right after it you'll see `RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1`

Read those two links and you'll get a better idea of what is going on.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-savepoint.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-release-savepoint.html

**More info 2** =)

As you can see on those two links, PostgreSQL creates a `SAVEPOINT`, saves the object and then `RELEASE SAVEPOINT`. It is not saving that data permanently, this isn't how `--sandbox` is meant to be used (IMO). The data is saved and right after that, "released". It is used for test purpose just to check if the relation between your models, validations, etc are OK.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I saw that, but according to the output, it appears to do an actual insert to the DB before the rollback on exit.  When in this mode, is it just "faking" the insert and rollback and never really writing to the DB?  In fact, the tutorial actually advises looking at the records in th DB to see the result of the commands. One difference is that the exercise assumes SQLite is the DB and I have switched to Postgres.

Comment: **More info** follow-up question: Thank you again.  That actually is very good to know.  However, I do not think I explained my case very well initially.   I am looking for the inserted data _before_ exiting the console (before the rollback) and expecting to see the data in the DB but am not.